# Инклюд сгенерированных autouic-ом файлов под виндой

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Имеется Qt-проект, использующий cmake для сборки под линукс, mingw и Visual Studio. Проблемы возникают, конечно, в третьем случае. AUTOUIC генерит `ui_*.h` хэдэры в папке вида `${PROJECT_NAME}_autogen/include` для нормальных систем, а в случае с генератором Visual Studio название папки с нормального меняется на что-то вроде `${PROJECT_NAME}_autogen/include_Debug`. Почему, и как это отключить?

PS не понимаю этих извращенцев, которые по доброй воли работают в VS, но так уж сложилось, что нужно и под них адаптировать проект.

Comment: это cmake,что-то колбасит, надо в нём смотреть, qmake для VS делает нормальные проекты

Comment: @PavelGridin Это Вы, капитан очевидность?

Comment: Сносите `VS`, это невозможно до следующего патча.

Comment: @beginer читайте ps. К тому же непонятно что сдесь невозможно?

Comment: Debug - это активная конфигурация проекта VS, он и сборки делает в разные папки при разных конфигурациях. Что в файле проекта cmake?

Comment: Самым простым решением будет добавить этот путь к списку путей для поиска включаемых файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-то это будет полезно:

Отключить (как я хотел) это, к сожалению нельзя, так что нужно расставить `if`-ы. В `cmake` для этого есть переменная `GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG`. Сгенеренные хэдэры же, должны подключаться примерно так:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_autogen/include_<CONFIG>")
```

и даже не пытайтесь выяснить (например вывести на экран) `<CONFIG>` во время конфигурирования - это невозможно.

PS Вообще `cmake` отрабатывает нормально с `ui` сгенеренными файлами и проблема, с которой я столкнулся, решалась гораздо проще: надавать по рукам тем, кто имеет привычку включать все что ни попадя в хидеры...